# error - doesn't work properly without JavaScript

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku

I've pushed a Node with a dist of Vue.js to Heroku and it deploys OK to Heroku, but when I call the API it gives me the following error:

> We're sorry but **app_example_name** doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.

I already check the chrome Javascript, but I believe that I'm missing something or just doing this wrong.

**Server.js**

```
c...
const serveStatic = require("serve-static")
const app = express()
const _port = process.env.PORT || 80

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));

app.use(cors());

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: 'Welcome to the API.'
  })
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/dist/index.html"));
});

app.get('/api/ddlGeneral', (req, res) => {
    const dbddlGeneral = fs.readFileSync('./db/ddls.json');
    const ddlArray = JSON.parse(dbddlGeneral);

    let _categorias = req.query.categorias;
    let _newArrayDdl = [];

    for (let loopDdls = 0; loopDdls < ddlArray.length; loopDdls++) {
      const _ddl = ddlArray[loopDdls];
      for (let _loopCategoria = 0; _loopCategoria < _categorias.length; _loopCategoria++) {
         if(_categorias[_loopCategoria] == _ddl.categoria){
          _newArrayDdl.push(ddlArray[loopDdls]);
        }
      }
    }

    res.json(_newArrayDdl);
})

app.listen(_port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${_port}`);
});
```

**mixin-code.js (In here lives Axios calls)**

```
import axios from 'axios';
const _port = process.env.PORT || 80
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "/api",
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
});

export const mixinDdlGeneral = async (payload) => {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
        let Result;

        try {
            Result = await instance.get('/ddlGeneral', {
                params: {
                    categories: [payload]
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.dir(error);
            return reject(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
        }

        return resolve(JSON.stringify({data: {
            queryddlsByCategory: Result.data
        }}));
    })
};
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "start": "node server"
  },
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

This error can appear when it fails from your nodejs side, and fail to add the dependencies that it will use nodejs correctly.

Maybe I missed to verify correctly the heroku logs to track in real time the stream.(commands: heroku logs -t or heroku logs --tail).